# Meteor mobile build not loading custom font/icon fonts

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, mobile, fonts

I have a meteor app that's using a downloaded package of [Material Design Icons](http://materialdesignicons.com/). When running for the web/mobile browser, all the icons are showing perfectly. However when I build for android, the icons do not show. I have the css and font files in a directory inside /public, so they are available to the client. The android version still doesn't display the icons. Here's what the mdi css looks like.

```
    @font-face {
      font-family: "Material Design Icons";
      src: url("/assets/mdi/css/materialdesignicons-webfont.eot?v=4.7.95");
      src: url("/assets/mdi/css/materialdesignicons-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.7.95") format("embedded-opentype"), url("/assets/mdi/css/materialdesignicons-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.95") format("woff2"), url("/assets/mdi/css/materialdesignicons-webfont.woff?v=4.7.95") format("woff"), url("/assets/mdi/css/materialdesignicons-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.95") format("truetype");
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
    }

    .mdi:before,
    .mdi-set {
      display: inline-block;
      font: normal normal normal 24px/1 "Material Design Icons";
      font-size: inherit;
      text-rendering: auto;
      line-height: inherit;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    }
```

This css file is in the same directory as the font files, I tried using both absolute and relative paths, but still doesn't work. Help.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem as follows:

1. Prepare the following structure

```
public
  css
    material-design-icons.css
  fonts
    MaterialIcons-Regular.eot
    MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf
    ...other icons
client
  main.js
```

2. set fonts in css file material-design-icons.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("./fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot");
  /* For IE6-8 */
  src: local("☺"), url("/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2") format("woff2"), url("/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff") format("woff"), url("/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf") format("truetype"); }

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

3. Import css file in main.js

```
import '../public/css/material-design-icons.css'
```